# Drag formula with importrange across column in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, copy, drag, importrange

I'm trying to drag formula with Importrange across column in google spreadsheets.

I managed to drag the formula down using `&row(A7)` but I'm not able to find a way to drag the formula across. 
Is there a similar function like `&column(A7)`?

For example:

```
=IF(Isnumber(SEARCH("(milk)",IMPORTRANGE("urlBlaBlaBla","Sheet1!A"&row(A7)))),"buy now",IF(Isnumber(SEARCH("(tea)",IMPORTRANGE("urlBlaBlaBla","Sheet1!A"&row(A7)))),"later"))
```

Dragging down does look like:

```
=IF(Isnumber(SEARCH("(milk)",IMPORTRANGE("urlBlaBlaBla","Sheet1!A"&row(A8)))),"buy now",IF(Isnumber(SEARCH("(tea)",IMPORTRANGE("urlBlaBlaBla","Sheet1!A"&row(A8)))),"later"))
```

Now I would like to drag that across in a way that it refers to the next column, so A changes to B, something like:

```
=IF(Isnumber(SEARCH("(milk)",IMPORTRANGE("urlBlaBlaBla","Sheet1!B"&row(B7)))),"buy now",IF(Isnumber(SEARCH("(tea)",IMPORTRANGE("urlBlaBlaBla","Sheet1!B"&row(B7)))),"later"))
```

but that above does not happen automatically.

Comment: If your goal is just to drag from one column to another you simply need to follow the syntax of [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340), `IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url, range_string)`. It could be like this `IMPORTRANGE("urlBlaBlaBla", "Sheet1!B:B")` to wherever column you want it to drag. That's how I understood your question.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Unfortunately that does not work on my sheet. If I drag "Sheet1!B:B" across to the next column, it remains as "Sheet1!B:B" or should I say the reference stays to the same cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have now in trying to pull "dynamic" column and row references into a string address function

```
"Sheet1!A"&row(A7))
```

`column(A1)` does not work because it brings in the column as an integer.  There are a couple of different solutions, in keeping the theme of bringing in the letter notation for the column you can use the left and cell functions:

```
left(CELL("address",A1),2)
```

(result for this function is "$A")

This is where we are using the `CELL` function to pull the string Address of A1 and then a `LEFT` function to get the column absolute reference for that column as a letter. Together it would be like:

```
="Sheet1!"&left(CELL("address",A1),2)&row(A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(INDEX((IMPORTRANGE("1Yhenq4iTZwPRtxro97tDw-xTA3lZ2XOCaqSSrNaSvd0/edit#gid=0","Nama&Kls!$H$3:$AD$3")),MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F2:F2,(IMPORTRANGE("1Yhenq4iTZwPRtxro97tDw-xTA3lZ2XOCaqSSrNaSvd0/edit#gid=0","Nama&Kls!$H$3:$AD$3")))*(SEARCH(1,(IMPORTRANGE("1Yhenq4iTZwPRtxro97tDw-xTA3lZ2XOCaqSSrNaSvd0/edit#gid=0","Nama&Kls!$H4:$AD4"
))))), 0)))),1,1)

How about this, if i want to change the last importrange, range_string from $H4:$AD4 to $H5:$AD5